# statsmodel.api.Logit: valueerror array must not contain infs or nans

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to apply Logistic Regression in Python using statsmodel.api.Logit. 
I am running into the error 
**ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs.**

When I am executing with:

```
data['intercept'] = 1.0
train_cols = data.columns[1:]
logit = sm.Logit(data['admit'], data[train_cols])
result = logit.fit(start_params=None, method='bfgs', maxiter=20, full_output=1, disp=1, callback=None)
```

The data contains more than 15000 columns and 2000 rows.
which data['admit'] is the target value and data[train_cols] is the list of features.
Can anyone please give me some hints to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

By default, `Logit` does not check your data for un-processable infinitities (`np.inf`) or NaNs (`np.nan`). In pandas, the latter normally signifies a missing entry.

To ignore rows with missing data and proceed with the rest, use `missing='drop'` like so:

```
sm.Logit(data['admit'], data[train_cols], missing='drop')
```

See the [Logit docs](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html?highlight=logit) for other options.

If you do not expect your data to contain any missing entries or infinities, perhaps you loaded it incorrectly. Look at `data[data.isnull()]` to see where the problem is. (N.B. [Read this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) to see how to make infs register as null.)